# JavaScript store integer number in localStorage, increase value and render data

Tags: javascript, local-storage

For my program the user inputs a number to see if this matches the computer guess.  To make things simple and I can better see the flow of the code the number to be guesses is between 0-1.
Issue I'm having is that I'm not properly saving the data to localStorage and incrementing the key value, if I manually add a value to my key localStorage only updates correctly when I refresh the page, each time I make a guess the program seems to respond correctly but have to refresh after the guess.  Any feedback would be appreciated.

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Guess # | Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guess Number Between 0-1</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="enter-value" placeholder="Enter a number"></input>
        <button id="submit-number">Submit</button>
        <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result-section"></div>
    <div id="count-section"></div>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

dom.js

```
    const submitNumber= document.getElementById('submit-number')
    const enterValue= document.getElementById('enter-value')
    const resultSection= document.getElementById('result-section')
    const countSection= document.getElementById('count-section')
    const resetButton= document.getElementById('reset-button')

    submitNumber.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        resultSection.textContent=''
        countSection.textContent=''
        const userNumInput= enterValue.value.trim()
        userGuess(userNumInput)
    })

    resetButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        localStorage.clear()
        countSection.textContent=''
        resetField()
        resultSection.textContent=''
    })

functions.js

let userTallyTotal
let computerTallyTotal 

const userGuess= (userNumber)=>{
    let message=''
    localStorage.getItem('userWinsTotal')!= null ? userTallyTotal : userTallyTotal= 0
    localStorage.getItem('computerWinsTotal')!= null ? computerTallyTotal : computerTallyTotal= 0
    //Current problem I'm facing now is that refreshing the page and submitting a value changes localStorage value to NaN

    let numberChoice= userNumber
    const randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*1)
    numberChoice= parseInt(numberChoice, 10)

    if (isNaN(numberChoice)){
        message+= 'This is not a number, try again.'
        displayResult(message)
        resetField()
        return
    }

    if (numberChoice===randomNum) {
        parseInt(userTallyTotal, 10)
        userTallyTotal++
        localStorage.setItem('userWinsTotal', userTallyTotal)
        message+= `You won! You guessed: ${numberChoice} and the computer guessed: ${randomNum}`
    } else {    
        parseInt(computerTallyTotal, 10)
        computerTallyTotal++
        localStorage.setItem('computerWinsTotal', computerTallyTotal)
        message+= `Sorry Try Again! You guessed: ${numberChoice} and the computer guessed: ${randomNum}`
    }
        resetField()
        displayResult(message)
        countWins(userTallyTotal,computerTallyTotal)
}

const displayResult= (message)=>{    
    const displayResultEl= document.createElement('h2')
    displayResultEl.textContent= message
    document.getElementById('result-section').appendChild(displayResultEl)
}

const countWins= (userTallyTotal, computerTallyTotal)=>{   
    const countWinsEl= document.createElement('h2')
    countWinsEl.textContent= `User Total Win: ${userTallyTotal} Computer Total Win: ${computerTallyTotal}`
    document.getElementById('count-section').appendChild(countWinsEl)
}

const resetField= ()=>{
    enterValue.value=''
    enterValue.focus()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `localStorage` can only hold strings, so `userWinsTotal` will be converted to string. Could you try to `Math.parseInt` it before the increment?

Comment: Appreciate it, I believe the edits below take care of that per your input.  Still working on other details.  Sorry about the comment formatting work in progress.

     `parseInt(userWinsTotal, 10)
        userWinsTotal++`

     `parseInt(computerWinsTotal, 10)
        computerWinsTotal++`

Comment: I revised my code as well, seems to work correctly although my userGuess function seems very messy with the if / else if statement.

Answer (score 0):

I found all problems:

1.`localStorage` , as mentioned by @Yesset Zhussupov, can store only strings so on reload you need to parse your consts:

```
const userTallyTotal= parseInt(localStorage.getItem('userWinsTotal'))
const computerTallyTotal= parseInt(localStorage.getItem('computerWinsTotal'))
```

2. You calling `userGuess` every time and you reseting your counters with:

```
userWinsTotal= userTallyTotal
computerWinsTotal= computerTallyTotal
```

where `userTallyTotal` and `computerTallyTotal` are `const`-type.
Fix for that is simply:

```
userWinsTotal= userWinsTotal||userTallyTotal
computerWinsTotal= computerWinsTotal||computerTallyTotal
```

Which will check if that variables are initialized or not

Comment: I revised my code fixed some items and it appears to work correctly, I'm sure my code under userGuess function in specific the if statement isn't the best approach.  I was trying to follow your feedback using but wasn't sure how to set it up.  Maybe you can provide some more feedback to see if this time I follow along?  Thanks.

Comment: userGuess function is set to use ternary operator and everything seems to work ok, except if I refresh page and submit a new value.  localStorage set value to NaN.  Working on fixing that and displaying the message if I refresh page and values were stored.  I updated my functions.js code as well for review if possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is my final code, tested and I no longer have the issue when refreshing the page. Appreciate the help and any final comments that could help me improve this as a beginner.
index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Guess # | Main</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Guess Number Between 0-1</h1>
    <form>
        <input id="enter-value" placeholder="Enter a number"></input>
        <button id="submit-number">Submit</button>
        <button id="reset-button">Reset</button>
    </form>
    <div id="result-section"></div>
    <div id="count-section"></div>
    <script src="functions.js"></script>
    <script src="dom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

dom.js

```
const submitNumber= document.getElementById('submit-number')
const enterValue= document.getElementById('enter-value')
const resultSection= document.getElementById('result-section')
const countSection= document.getElementById('count-section')
const resetButton= document.getElementById('reset-button')

submitNumber.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    resultSection.textContent=''
    countSection.textContent=''
    const userNumInput= enterValue.value.trim()
    userGuess(userNumInput)
})

resetButton.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    localStorage.clear()
    countSection.textContent=''
    resultSection.textContent=''
    resetField()
    countWins(0,0)
})
```

functions.js

```
let userTallyTotal= localStorage.getItem('userWinsTotal')
let computerTallyTotal= localStorage.getItem('computerWinsTotal')

const checkStoredData=()=>{
    localStorage.getItem('userWinsTotal')!= null ? userTallyTotal : userTallyTotal= 0
    localStorage.getItem('computerWinsTotal')!= null ? computerTallyTotal : computerTallyTotal= 0
}

const userGuess= (userNumber)=>{
    checkStoredData()
    let message=''
    let numberChoice= userNumber
    const randomNum= Math.floor(Math.random()*1)
    numberChoice= parseInt(numberChoice, 10)

    if (isNaN(numberChoice)){
        message+= 'This is not a number, try again.'
        displayResult(message)
        resetField()
        return
    }
    
    if (numberChoice===randomNum) {
        parseInt(userTallyTotal, 10)
        userTallyTotal++
        localStorage.setItem('userWinsTotal', userTallyTotal)
        message+= `You won! You guessed: ${numberChoice} and the computer guessed: ${randomNum}`
    } else {    
        parseInt(computerTallyTotal, 10)
        computerTallyTotal++
        localStorage.setItem('computerWinsTotal', computerTallyTotal)
        message+= `Sorry Try Again! You guessed: ${numberChoice} and the computer guessed: ${randomNum}`
    }
        resetField()
        displayResult(message)
        countWins(userTallyTotal,computerTallyTotal)
}

const displayResult= (message)=>{    
    const displayResultEl= document.createElement('h2')
    displayResultEl.textContent= message
    document.getElementById('result-section').appendChild(displayResultEl)
}

const countWins= (userTallyTotal, computerTallyTotal)=>{    
    const countWinsEl= document.createElement('h2')
    countWinsEl.textContent= `User Total Win: ${userTallyTotal || 0} Computer Total Win: ${computerTallyTotal || 0}`
    document.getElementById('count-section').appendChild(countWinsEl)
}

const resetField= ()=>{
    enterValue.value=''
    enterValue.focus()
    countSection.textContent=''
}

countWins(userTallyTotal, computerTallyTotal)
```